# Find variables with the greatest variance within different groups

Tags: r, logistic-regression, large-data

I am trying to run a regression model, where I would like to find the best predictors. However, the data contains more than 100,000 variables (it's a microarray-based experiment) and 2 outcomes (tumor and non-tumor). Here's an a snapshot of the data:

```
>dt
       Tumor cg15560884   cg15979415 cg21482377 cg27346986 cg13565718  cg04359978 cg00328058 cg07787977 cg02632261
    1     No -0.2480779 -3.541635298  0.1930965 -0.2855506  1.7873570 -0.05663302 -0.3248885 -2.9448065  0.6228754
    2     No  0.9172439  0.055514083  0.4655855  0.3226286  2.0404916  1.93954213  1.0556121  0.1188842  0.6394047
    3     No  0.4115322 -2.688796456 -0.3414734 -0.5690240  1.4191325  0.23146577 -0.3843809 -2.3456532  2.1169214
    4     No  0.9564983 -0.284362579  0.9074372  0.3841181  1.9482238  2.30368166  1.6791506  0.1672436  1.8456432
    5     No  0.4373796 -0.847716026 -0.3654539  0.6407850  0.4981430  1.41772759  0.1211819 -0.3048053  0.9258699
    6     No  1.1842945  0.184265452 -0.5769016  0.2349631  0.4897802  1.96881485  2.1653989 -0.2689008 -0.7468990
    7     No  1.2802583  1.510712751 -0.4231337 -0.2016259  2.7457824  2.78922437  2.1925534  0.5288933  1.0394935
    8    Yes  1.1831400  0.103893327  0.3585823  0.5774059  2.9961775  3.00736681  1.9211571  1.9990507  2.5718125
    9    Yes  1.1419304  0.009477014  1.7524348  0.6827657  3.1542609  3.11282241  2.3964859  1.2965353  2.9299558
    10   Yes  1.5811014  2.612363269  4.0609050  2.5058440  3.4295390  2.74999398  3.5159891  4.0156051  4.1311138
    11   Yes  0.4145909 -0.375025614  0.2912988  0.3032374  3.1445856  2.20233921  0.8775737  0.8418369  1.9903667
    12   Yes  0.9668263 -0.272698105 -0.1731778  0.2230170  2.5546191  1.91083215  2.3383876  2.3296599  2.1821964
    13   Yes -0.1230484 -0.625187944  0.2620956 -0.0419292  2.9346895  2.45153644  1.9039218  1.5932535  2.4690055
    14   Yes  0.8659252  0.175015222  1.0062097  0.3605752  2.0769247  1.52875829  1.5361073  0.8493504  2.3467234
```

I have performed a series of logit analyses that do seem to be fine to perform. Briefly, that's the pipeline:

1. Linear model for a series of arrays (`lmFit()`) with empirical Bayes approach (`eBayes()`):

```
#Designing the contrast model:
design <- data.frame(Tumor=c(rep("0", 7), rep("1", 7)), Benign=c(rep("1", 7), rep("0", 7)))

#Running linear regression with empirical Bayes approach:
lmFit(dt[,-1], design) %>% eBayes() -> fit
```

2. Univariate analysis (`glm()`) for found candidates (P< 0.05):

```
glm(Tumor ~ [*], family=binomial(link='logit'), data=dt)
```

3. Multivariate analysis with lasso penalty and cross-validation (`cv.glmnet()`) for found candidates (P< 0.05).
   That's because the number of found candidates is quite large (> 1,000 candiates):

```
#This is just an example (i.e. these are not necessarily the candidates).
x <- model.matrix(as.formula(c("~cg15560884 + cg15979415 + cg21482377 + cg27346986 + cg13565718 + cg04359978 + cg00328058 + cg07787977 + cg02632261")), dt)
y <- dt$Tumor

cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family="binomial", standardize=T, alpha=1, nfolds=10, data=dt)
```

At this step, there are approximately **25 candidates** which passed all the analyses.

When I plot those potential candiates, I see however that the variance between the 2 groups (*tumor* x *non-tumor*) is not really that great for some of them. And as the intention here is to look for some candidates that have potential clinical relevance, here is the question:

#### What would be the best approach to identify variables with (1) low variance within the same group and (2) clear, relatively high difference between them?

I thought about starting off the pipeline with [*Sum of squares between groups*](https://www.statisticshowto.com/between-group-variation/), or alike, but I am not sure what the best method(s) would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: And here is the mock data presented above:

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(Tumor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    cg15560884 = c(-0.248077910261345, 0.917243931527906, 0.411532204288758, 
    0.956498270834689, 0.437379596251596, 1.18429454839675, 1.28025825354934, 
    1.18313995574906, 1.14193044361971, 1.58110142968133, 0.414590861304658, 
    0.966826317765609, -0.123048367553966, 0.865925151474944), 
    cg15979415 = c(-3.54163529762454, 0.0555140832614802, -2.68879645560804, 
    -0.284362579485303, -0.847716026488968, 0.184265451680517, 
    1.51071275115752, 0.103893326861259, 0.00947701421375391, 
    2.61236326867269, -0.375025613783568, -0.272698105021754, 
    -0.62518794357036, 0.175015221908592), cg21482377 = c(0.19309650443158, 
    0.465585470446969, -0.341473357667879, 0.907437241260519, 
    -0.36545393340153, -0.576901593963131, -0.423133690212283, 
    0.358582311092238, 1.75243481045574, 4.06090501077815, 0.291298796940103, 
    -0.173177826492712, 0.262095579024894, 1.00620967854383), 
    cg27346986 = c(-0.285550598277455, 0.322628631286669, -0.569023984702458, 
    0.384118141327422, 0.640785025494895, 0.234963083143655, 
    -0.201625866484334, 0.577405892650868, 0.682765746636268, 
    2.50584400408156, 0.303237442139183, 0.223016985745948, -0.0419291977006327, 
    0.360575219255877), cg13565718 = c(1.78735699619159, 2.04049160554018, 
    1.41913246191327, 1.94822376321837, 0.498142972793614, 0.489780156080168, 
    2.74578238467836, 2.99617752225596, 3.15426093568808, 3.42953897985088, 
    3.14458563100296, 2.55461911595142, 2.93468952565516, 2.07692465631039
    ), cg04359978 = c(-0.056633023447488, 1.93954212965755, 0.231465769910894, 
    2.30368165948499, 1.41772758917327, 1.96881485075863, 2.78922437354038, 
    3.00736681386976, 3.11282240855254, 2.74999398469954, 2.2023392119177, 
    1.91083214812378, 2.45153643876517, 1.52875829347186), cg00328058 = c(-0.324888517874121, 
    1.05561214264499, -0.384380901476841, 1.67915058188375, 0.121181903594745, 
    2.16539894626557, 2.19255343382776, 1.9211570874648, 2.39648589262158, 
    3.51598910725581, 0.877573664935301, 2.33838763841662, 1.90392175186133, 
    1.53610733484261), cg07787977 = c(-2.94480653748164, 0.118884228237407, 
    -2.34565316735368, 0.167243632510614, -0.304805256674929, 
    -0.268900821807674, 0.528893346493377, 1.99905071007526, 
    1.29653531766456, 4.01560505952943, 0.841836891217517, 2.32965985284038, 
    1.5932534862773, 0.849350444895923), cg02632261 = c(0.622875369361909, 
    0.63940465080861, 2.11692137500146, 1.84564321288801, 0.925869893712036, 
    -0.746898982059526, 1.03949352765268, 2.57181250869727, 2.9299557731721, 
    4.13111383622201, 1.9903666807218, 2.18219637136446, 2.46900554766421, 
    2.34672341454479)), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: any particular reason you're not using t-tests?

Comment: Thank you @anakar. I'm sorry, it wasn't clear on the methods above. The first part, ```lmFit()``` + ```eBayes()```, does return a moderated t-statistics.